# iphone packager and sampledataevent supported?

Tags: flash, audio, air

I want to know has anybody successully implemented an audio sampledataevent using the adobe iphone packager?

I've being trying to do this recently but the audio does not play smoothly. Also I've tried a range of different buffer sizes but this too was unsuccessful.

```
function sampleDataHandler(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{


 var l:Number;
 var r:Number;
 var len = soundFactory.extract(buffer,bufferSize);

 if (len < bufferSize)
 {
  soundFactory.extract(buffer,bufferSize-len,0);
 }

 buffer.position = 0;

 for (var i:int=0; i<bufferSize; ++i)
 {
  l = buffer.readFloat();
  r = buffer.readFloat();
  e.data.writeFloat(l);
  e.data.writeFloat(r);
 }

 buffer.clear()
}
```

I also tried just generating a simple sine wave in case there was something wrong with the mp3 decoding but this failed as well.

```
function sampleDataHandler(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
 for (var c:int=0; c<bufferSize; c++)
 {
 event.data.writeFloat(Math.sin((Number(c+event.position)/Math.PI/2))*0.25);
 event.data.writeFloat(Math.sin((Number(c+event.position)/Math.PI/2))*0.25);
 }

}
```

Comment: Is that asterisk in there for a reason?

Comment: twas a type-o. it's fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at present it's not possible